# SQL query conversion to Hive supported migration SQL

Tags: postgresql, hive, hiveql, greenplum

I am migrating the greenplum SQL query to HiveSQL, kindly help me as below statement.

```
select (date_trunc('week',current_date) - INTERVAL '7 week')::DATE 
select (date_trunc('week',current_date)+ '6 days'::INTERVAL)::DATE
select date_trunc('week',current_date)::DATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are equivalent queries -

```
select (date_trunc('week',current_date) - INTERVAL '7 week')::DATE --> select date_sub(next_day(date_sub(current_date, 7), 'MON'), 49)
select (date_trunc('week',current_date)+ '6 days'::INTERVAL)::DATE --> select date_add(next_day(date_sub(current_date, 7), 'MON'), 6)
select date_trunc('week',current_date)::DATE --> select next_day(date_sub(current_date, 7), 'MON')
```

All above solution are using next_day() function which picks up next MONDAY from current date -7 days. And then first scrnario adds 7week/49days, second one adds 6 days, and third one just get Monday of current date.

Comment: select (date_trunc('week',current_date)+ '6 days'::INTERVAL)::DATE -if we run this query in GP, i am getting result :  2022-03-20

Comment: based on your answer, i updated the answer.

Comment: how are you calculating 49? what basis we have to put this value. please let me know

Comment: select (date_trunc('week',current_date) - INTERVAL '2 week')::DATE
select date_sub(next_day(date_sub(current_date, 7), 'MON'), 14)   -- this is right?

Comment: Assuming 1week =7days, 7weeks meams 49days. Based on above, your sql is correct.